# Como faço para responder uma pergunta aqui no stackoverflow?

Tags: debate

Estou vendo várias perguntas que posso ajudar mas não encontro o botão para responder.

Segue abaixo um exemplo:

[A cada segundo somar 1 na variavel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/324670/a-cada-segundo-somar-1-na-variavel-php)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloca um print de como aparece na sua tela.

Comment: A pergunta que você quer responder está fechada.

Comment: como eu sei que esta fechada?

Comment: Tem um banner amarelo logo abaixo da pergunta dizendo que ela está fechada.

Comment: @MateusGabriel Tem uma notificação entre colchetes *[]* ao lado do título da pergunta. Veja esses exemplos: *blablabla?[pendente]*  ; *trolololo?[Duplicada]*

Comment: ja entendi, agora queria marcar esta pergunta como resolvida kkk

Comment: Ela já está sendo considerada como resolvida, o aceite em uma resposta garante isso. O Que acontece é que o stackoverflow não fecha perguntas respondidas, pois dessa forma ele permite a inserção de novas respostas que podem complementar a inicialmente aceita.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Caro Mateus, essa pergunta ai esta muito **vaga**, ou seja mesmo que você dê uma resposta provavelmente é um problema mais amplo e o autor talvez venha a dizer que sua resposta não resolve, eu já passei por isto muitas vezes.

Mesmo que não fosse uma pergunta "ampla", provavelmente já tem outras perguntas com respostas que resolveriam o problema dela, o que tornaria ela uma duplicata.

Aliais se você notar uma pergunta pesquise antes para ver se já não tem pergunta igual com resposta, e então sinalize como `deveria ser fechada...` > `Duplicata` ao invés de responder o que provavelmente possui boas respostas. Só responda mesmo se acreditar que as respostas em outras perguntas não cobrem o assunto ou não são detalhadas, claro que nisso é esperado um esforço de sua parte para criar uma resposta verdadeiramente útil a comunidade, não só ao autor da pergunta.

### Como sinalizar perguntas duplicatas

Clique no link "sinalizar" abaixo da pergunta:

> [image: sinalizar pergunta]

Selecione `deveria ser fechada`:

[image: opção deveria ser fechada]

Selecione a opção `duplicata de`:

[image: opção duplicata de]

Então no campo cole a URL de outra pergunta que acredita resolver o problema da pergunta atual:

[image: campo para buscar duplicatas]

---

### Reabrindo

No entanto pode ser que o autor da pergunta queira algo bem mais especifico e que realmente não tenha resposta, para isto é necessário que ele edite a pergunta e explique a sua necessidade com clareza, fazendo isso provavelmente saberemos se já existe resposta ou não, se não existir então 5 pessoas votando para reabrir a pergunta irá reativa-la e assim você terá a oportunidade de responder algo sem sofrer com uma "pergunta camaleão".

Answer (score 7):

A pergunta em questão está fechada, portanto não pode receber respostas. Ninguém pode postar respostas nela até ser reaberta, o que só poderá ocorrer quando o problema dela for resolvido. Em perguntas abertas já tem um *textarea* aberto pra responder e um botão para enviar.

Dá para saber que a pergunta está fechada porque está escrito isso no bloco amarelo que aparece logo abaixo dela. Lá tem instruções de como pode melhorar para ser respondida, mas é mais para i autor dela, o único que consegue dar mais detalhes. O que pode ser feito é comentar (quando tiver 50 pontos) para pedir para a pessoas postar isso. Outros já o fizeram.

Ela não tem um problema definido, apenas diz o que quer e alguém tem que adivinhar o que é adequado ali. Qualquer resposta pode ser certa ou errada, ninguém sabe, provavelmente nem quem perguntou, porque não tem critério, restrição, definição detalhada, tentativa de fazer um código, um contexto, nada.